# Write null bytes in a file instead of correct strings

Tags: python

I have a python script that process a data file :

```
out = open('result/process/'+name+'.res','w')
out.write("source,rssi,lqi,packetId,run,counter\n")
f = open('result/resultat0.res','r')
for ligne in [x for x in f if x != '']:
    chaine = ligne.rstrip('\n')
    tmp = chaine.split(',')
    if (len(tmp) == 6 ):
        out.write(','.join(tmp)+"\n")
f.close()
```

The complete code is [here](http://pastebin.com/CsqMPp6R)

I use this script on several computers and the behavior is not the same.
On the first computer, with python 2.6.6, the result is what I expect.
However, on the others (python 2.6.6, 3.3.2, 2.7.5) the write method of file object puts null bytes instead of the values I want during the most part of the processing. I get this result :

```
$ hexdump -C result/process/1.res
00000000  73 6f 75 72 63 65 2c 72  73 73 69 2c 6c 71 69 2c  |source,rssi,lqi,|
00000010  70 61 63 6b 65 74 49 64  2c 72 75 6e 2c 63 6f 75  |packetId,run,cou|
00000020  6e 74 65 72 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |nter............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
0003a130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 31 33 2c 36 35 2c  |..........13,65,|
0003a140  31 34 2c 38 2c 39 38 2c  31 33 31 34 32 0a 31 32  |14,8,98,13142.12|
0003a150  2c 34 37 2c 31 37 2c 38  2c 39 38 2c 31 33 31 34  |,47,17,8,98,1314|
0003a160  33 0a 33 2c 34 35 2c 31  38 2c 38 2c 39 38 2c 31  |3.3,45,18,8,98,1|
0003a170  33 31 34 34 0a 31 31 2c  38 2c 32 33 2c 38 2c 39  |3144.11,8,23,8,9|
0003a180  38 2c 31 33 31 34 35 0a  39 2c 32 30 2c 32 32 2c  |8,13145.9,20,22,|
```

Have you an idea how to resolve this problem please ?

Comment: I've had a look at the complete code in the link. You're new to python and object oriented programming? The problem is that you're using globals and opening files in various places, storing file handles in dictionaries: it's pretty unintelligible. Your code desperately needs refactoring.

Comment: Some general remarks. Have you tried a debugger? Add a print-statement in your list-comprehension to verify that the output is as expected. Instead of using `rstrip`, try `strip()` to remove all line-ending-characters, including trailing spaces.

Comment: I tried using print-statement and the output was the right line, not null bytes.

Comment: `fd=open('foo', 'wb'); fd.write('\x00'*50); fd.close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following considerations:

- In over a decade of programming python, I've never come across a compelling reason to use `global`. Pass arguments to functions instead.
- For ensuring files are closed when finished with, use the [with statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Here's an (untested) attempt at refactoring your code for sanity, assumes that you have enough memory available to hold all of the lines under a particular identifier.

If you have null bytes in your result files after this refactoring then we have reasonable basis to proceed with debugging.

```
import os
import re
from contextlib import closing

def list_files_to_process(directory='results'):
  """
  Return a list of files from directory where the file extension is '.res',
  case insensitive.
  """
  results = []
  for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    filepath = os.path.join(directory,filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath) and filename.lower().endswith('.res'):
      results.append(filepath)
  return results

def group_lines(sequence):
  """
  Generator, process a sequence of lines, separated by a particular line.
  Yields batches of lines along with the id from the separator.
  """
  separator = re.compile('^A:(?P<id>\d+):$')
  batch = []
  batch_id = None
  for line in sequence:
    if not line: # Ignore blanks
      continue
    m = separator.match(line):
    if m is not None:
      if batch_id is not None or len(batch) > 0:
        yield (batch_id,batch)
      batch_id = m.group('id')
      batch = []
    else:
      batch.append(line)
  if batch_id is not None or len(batch) > 0:
    yield (batch_id,batch)

def filename_for_results(batch_id,result_directory):
  """
  Return an appropriate filename for a batch_id under the result directory
  """
  return os.path.join(result_directory,"results-%s.res" % (batch_id,))

def open_result_file(filename,header="source,rssi,lqi,packetId,run,counter"):
  """
  Return an open file object in append mode, having appended a header if 
  filename doesn't exist or is empty
  """
  if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
    # No need to write header
    return open(filename,'a')
  else:
    f = open(filename,'a')
    f.write(header + '\n')
    return f

def process_file(filename,result_directory='results/processed'):
  """
  Open filename and process it's contents. Uses group_lines() to group
  lines into different files based upon specific line acting as a
  content separator.
  """
  error_filename = filename_for_results('error',result_directory)
  with open(filename,'r') as in_file, open(error_filename,'w') as error_out:
    for batch_id, lines in group_lines(in_file):
      if len(lines) == 0:
        error_out.write("Received batch %r with 0 lines" % (batch_id,))
        continue
      out_filename = filename_for_results(batch_id,result_directory)
      with closing(open_result_file(out_filename)) as out_file:
        for line in lines:
          if line.startswith('L') and line.endswith('E') and line.count(',') == 5:
            line = line.lstrip('L').rstrip('E')
            out_file.write(line + '\n')
          else:
            error_out.write("Unknown line, batch=%r: %r\n" %(batch_id,line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  files = list_files_to_process()
  for filename in files:
    print "Processing %s" % (filename,)
    process_file(filename)
```

Comment: It works with some minor corrections (There was a newline in the end of each line). Thanks !!!

Comment: @user2523255: You're welcome. For some reason I mistakenly thought that iterating a file object ate the newlines. It fixes your null bytes issue too?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't work on python 2.6 and 3.x(the formatted string doesn't work), but it works on 2.7